# Get href from link and attach it to another link

Tags: jquery, href

I actually have working code for this problem, but I think it's probably not very efficient. I think I could probably combine it into one, but my knowledge of JS is still limited enough that I'm not sure how to do it.

The problem:
I have 3 slider divs on the homepage. Each div has an H5 title tag wrapped in an unpopulated `<a>` tag. So I need to pull the href from each div's .slideshow-button and apply it to the h5 tag. (Weird problem, but just go with it.)

The (inefficient? but working) solution:

```
$('.homepage-slideshow:first-child .title-controls a').attr('href', $('.homepage-slideshow:first-child .slideshow-buttons a').attr('href')); 
$('.homepage-slideshow:nth-child(2) .title-controls a').attr('href', $('.homepage-slideshow:nth-child(2) .slideshow-buttons a').attr('href')); 
$('.homepage-slideshow:nth-child(3) .title-controls a').attr('href', $('.homepage-slideshow:nth-child(3) .slideshow-buttons a').attr('href'));
```

Can I combine these into one, so I don't have to do it 3 separate times?

Comment: at a minimum it would be faster to not do the same selector twice 3 times...instead save to `var` and then use the `var`, but from a glance yes this can be made more efficient that just that improvement.

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming you need to change links within each of your `.homepage-slideshow`):

```
$('.homepage-slideshow').each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var href = $this.find('.slideshow-buttons a').attr('href');
   $this.find('.title-controls a').attr('href', href);
});
```

Comment: That worked! I was trying variations on '$this', but didn't know about 'find'. Thank you for your help.